# Log all request from flex / BlazeDS client using filter

Tags: apache-flex, spring, filter, request, blazeds

I have a spring BlazeDS integration  application.  I would like to log all the request.

I planned to use Filter.  In my filter when I check the request parameter. It does not contain anything related to the client request. If I change the order of my filter(I have spring Security), then it prints some thing related to spring security.

I am unable to log the user request.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done the same functionality by using AOP (AspectJ) to inject a logger statement into communication endpoint methods. -- May this is an alternative approach for you too.

---

```
/** Logger advice and pointcuts for flex remoting stuff based on aspect J*/
public aspect AspectJInvocationLoggerAspect {

    /** The name of the used logger. */
    public final static String LOGGER_NAME = "myPackage.FLEX_INVOCATION_LOGGER";

    /** Logger used to log messages. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);

    AspectJInvocationLoggerAspect() {
    }

    /**
     * Pointcut for all flex remoting methods.
     * 
     * Flex remoting methods are determined by two constraints:
     * <ul>
     *   <li>they are public</li>
     *   <li>the are located in a class of name Remoting* within (implement an interface)
     *   {@link com.example.remote} package</li>
     *   <li>they are located within a class with an {@link RemotingDestination} annotation</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    pointcut remotingServiceFunction()
        : (execution(public * com.example.remote.*.*Remote*.*(..)))  
        && (within(@RemotingDestination *));

    before() : remotingServiceFunction() {
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            Signature sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
            Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();

            String location = sig.getDeclaringTypeName() + '.' + sig.getName() + ", args=" + Arrays.toString(args);            
            LOGGER.debug(location + " - begin");
        }
    }

    /** Log flex invocation result at TRACE level. */
    after() returning (Object result): remotingServiceFunction() {

        if (LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) {
            Signature sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();            

            String location = sig.getDeclaringTypeName() + '.' + sig.getName();
            LOGGER.trace(location + " - end = " + result);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the reason for choosing filter is I wanted to handle all kind of clients, MVC and flex. I have googled a lot and the nearest I could find was http://www.spltech.co.uk/blog/struts-2/integrating-adobe-flex-with-struts-2-and-jboss-using-blazeds    But if I can't find a clean soultion using filter, then I have to switch to interceptors or AOP .  So Can you throw some light or some links, on how to do the same using AOP.

Comment: @user1057094: i have added an example

Comment: Thanks for the example. I will give it a try. But I still wonder, how to do this using filter.